# Scalamock Proxymock, is a 'does not expect' possible to implement

Tags: scala, mocking

I have a class in which I am passing in a mocked service.  This class has caching so if I run the method twice I would expect the function called on the service on the first run not to be called on the second.  Is there a way of testing that, ie

```
mock expects 'function never
```

or

```
mock not expects 'function
```

Comment: Did you try the first expression? ``never`` is available (http://scalamock.org/api/org/scalamock/Expectation.html) and using it should be straight-forward (http://scalamock.org/api/org/scalamock/package.html).

Comment: I have an expression 
"mock expects 'function withArgs (arg1,arg2) returns (result)"

I then execute
I then add
"mock expects 'function never"
and execute again, and this does not error when I remove caching.
It wont let me add once to the first expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't notice never or once are functions, so any directly following code is seen as arguments, so leave a blank line, use a ;, or set the empty parameters

eg:

```
mock expects 'function never()
```

or,

```
mock expects 'function withArgs(arg1, arg2) returns true once()
```

Comment: You could add a working example and then accept your own answer.

Comment: Good point, though it won't let me accept unless its been up for two days, in truth I felt a  bit foolish I didn't recognise this before posting the question:)